# Woocommerce : Generate a unique key per item and send it in the order email

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I would like that when a user orders items, a special unique key is generated for each item. These keys / This key should then be visible in ALL order mails (admin and customer). Here is what I tried to do after some research around the web :

```
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_processing', 'process_membership_order');
//Trying to generate my keys for each item
function process_membership_order($order_id) {
    $order = new WC_Order($order_id);
    $items = $order->get_items(); 
    foreach ($items as $item_id => $product) {
        $key_id = "TESTING123"; //testing purpose of course, will call a function later
        wc_add_order_item_meta($item_id, 'custom_key', $key_id);
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_meta', 'add_email_order_meta', 10, 3 );
//Trying to edit the email order infos
function add_email_order_meta($order_obj, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text){
    $key = get_post_meta( $order_obj->get_order_number(), 'custom_key', true );
    if ( $plain_text === false ) {
        echo "<h2>Custom Information</h2><p>$key</p>";
    } else {
        echo "CUSTOM INFORMATION : $key";   
    }
}
```

It doesn't seem to work, my mails have the new title but it's always empty instead of showing my TESTING123 as many times as there is an item. I'm more a tinkerer than a dev, I've used an entire day on this, a little push on the right direction would be really appreciated, I think I'm close but something's missing ! Anyway, any advice would be great, thank you.

Comment: Looks like you are adding your meta data to the individual items, but then when you try to read it back, you are trying to do that via the order id, not the actual item ID(s).

Comment: Thanks, now that I know what was wrong it seems painfully obvious !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to get order items from the order object and then you can get your custom meta by using `wc_get_order_item_meta`. check below code.

```
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_processing', 'process_membership_order');
//Trying to generate my keys for each item
function process_membership_order($order_id) {
    $order = new WC_Order($order_id);
    $items = $order->get_items(); 
    foreach ($items as $item_id => $product) {
        $key_id = "TESTING123"; //testing purpose of course, will call a function later
        wc_add_order_item_meta($item_id, 'custom_key', $key_id);
    }
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_meta', 'add_email_order_meta', 10, 3 );
//Trying to edit the email order infos
function add_email_order_meta($order_obj, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text){

    $order = wc_get_order( $order_obj->get_order_number() );
    $items = $order->get_items(); 

    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {

        $key = wc_get_order_item_meta( $item_id, 'custom_key', true ); 

        if ( $plain_text === false ) {
            echo "<h2>Custom Information</h2><p>$key</p>";
        } else {
            echo "CUSTOM INFORMATION : $key";   
        }

    }

}
```